# How can I run a follow-up survey HIT with the same set of Workers in Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, mechanicalturk

I'm working on a longitudinal research study where we need to re-survey the same set of Workers.

A complication: I'm doing this with a new MTurk Requester account, as access to the original one isn't readily available. Therefore the previous project & batch are not there. I'm making a new project.

I have the MTurk IDs for the past Workers though.

Will this be enough, or will I need to access the old MTurk Requester account? If it is enough, how can I do this?

So far, I attempted to import the Worker list, and set a qualification that only those workers could participant in this next HIT. But I'm not sure how I can notify those specific Workers that there is a follow-up intended for them.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot contact workers who have not worked for you (on that requester account) previously.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do if I were you would be to name the qualification something like "Follow-up HIT posted just for you please check it out http://shorturl.to/yourHIT". Turkers get an email when a qualification is granted, so this will notify them and they'll be curious enough to check it out.

If I didn't get enough Ps, I'd log into the old account and send a message to the workers through the API asking them to participate in the new HIT.

Comment: Hi, this is quite an innovative idea.


How confirmed is this? (Turkers get an email when a "specific" qualification is granted.)


Because I've granted the relevant MTurk IDs that qualification, but with my current MTurk account they've never done a HIT for me. Will they still get that notification?

Comment: I've been a Turker for 12 years and a Requester for 10. I can confirm it. :) The notification is sent out whenever a qualification is granted, regardless of whether they've worked for you before or not. It's a neat little trick I picked up from another Requester.